# GetInt can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, properties, unity-game-engine

I am working on vehicle game. I wrote BaseVehicle class like this;

```
public class BaseVehicle
{
    private string name;
    private int speed;
    private int level;

    public string Name
    {
        get{return name;}
        set{name = value;}
    }

    public int Speed
    {
        get{return speed;}
        set{speed = value;}
    }

    public int Level
    {
        get{return level;}
        set{level = value;}
    }
}
```

this is working well. But I tried to set level value with PlayerPrefs, console gives error("GetInt can only be called from the main thread.").

```
public class Car : BaseVehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "965 Cabriolet";
        Speed = 250;
        Level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CarLevel");//There is a error, how can i call PlayerPrefs in to this class.
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't providing enough detail. How are you instantiating this class?  What is PlayerPrefs?  The way you appear to be using it, it looks like it's a static class.  Am I right?

Comment: PlayerPrefs is [Unity3d library](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class.

Comment: See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/754680/playerpref-problems.html

Comment: I know how to use PlayerPrefs I looked answer in unityforums but I couldnt find it, question is how can i use it in my Car class?

Comment: Is Car a member of a MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject? Where is it instantiated?

Comment: Car is not a member of BaseVehicle,but inherits from it. Where do you instantiate it?

Comment: I will use on my GarageGUI script like this. private BaseVehicle car = new Car();    void Start(){ Debug.Log(car.Name); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are calling `PlayerPref.GetInt` before the normal execution of main loop.

You are calling `PlayerPref.GetInt` in a field declaration of a `MonoBehavior` (`private BaseVehicle car = new Car();`). At this time, the "normal execution" of unity has not yet begun.

You can only call `PlayerPref.GetInt` in events of Unity like `Awake()`, `Start()` , `Update()`, etc.

My suggestion is:

```
private BaseVehicle car;

void Awake() {
    car = new Car();
}
```

This probably works.